# how to retrieve data from the database based on key array each have value?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have an array like this

```
Array ( 
    [14] => 0.46902846738366
    [16] => 0.40289063077504
    [17] => 0.54903658244928 
)
```

14, 16, 17 are at the same array key id of my tables that are in the database. how do I can access my information from a database table based on the key array (14, 16, 17)?

we assume that in the table there is a lot of data that is stored but I just wanted to take the data with id 14, 16, 17. The selected later from the id that I will perform mathematical operations to find the value of the highest of the three.?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here... you want to know how to do a SQL: "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ???"

Comment: `SELECT data FROM table WHERE id IN (14,16,17)`

Comment: no, I want to use the condition where dynamically rather than manually. where the condition is based on key array I have

Comment: Read about [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) functions. Then substitute the result to your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arry = array(14 => 0.46902846738366,16 => 0.40289063077504,17 =>0.54903658244928 );
$idarray=array_keys($arry);

"SELECT data FROM table WHERE id IN (".implode(',',$idarray).")";
```

Answer (score 1):

to get rows using ids put this code in your model(let's call it model)

```
function get($ids) {
return $this->db->where_in('id', $ids)->order_by->('my_col_name')->get('storage')->result(); // or result_array();
}
```

and call it like this

```
$data = $this->model->get(array_keys($zip_array));// or $this->model->get($array_a); from your last question
```

data in $data will be sorted from max value to low value, so automatically you got the max one too ! just need to change my_col_name to your column name

update: of course you can only select max value, if you want this, change get() to this

```
return $this->db->where_in('id', $ids)->select_max('my_col_name')->get('storage')->row();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myArray = array ( 
    '14' => 0.46902846738366,
    '16' => 0.40289063077504,
    '17' => 0.54903658244928,
) ;

$myArrayForQuery = implode(',',array_keys($myArray));

$myQuery = 'SELECt * FROM mytable where id in ( '.$myArrayForQuery.' );';
```